# Using Get-AzureStorageFileContent to execute SQL script from Azure Storage file share

Tags: powershell, azure-storage-files, invoke-sqlcmd

I am using Invoke-Sqlcmd to pick up -InputFile from an Azure Storage File share. I am using the Get-AzureStorageFileContent to get the file from Azure Storage but getting the error below. Any help or insight is appreciated.

Get-AzureStorageFileContent : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. HTTP Status Code: 404 - HTTP Error Message: The specified resource does not exist.
At line:35 char:1

Below is the Powershell script:

```
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $azureStorageAccount -StorageAccountKey $storageKey
Get-AzureStorageFileContent -ShareName $azureFileShare -Path $azureFilePath -Destination $destination -Context  $ctx 
# Set Connection parameters
$params = @{
    'Database' = $Database
    'ServerInstance' = $ServerInstance
    'Username' = $dbusername
    'Password' = $dbpassword
    'InputFile' = $ctx+'\'+$scriptFile

}

Invoke-Sqlcmd @params
```

Comment: `Invoke-Sqlcmd` is irrelevant here. The thing that is failing `Get-AzureStorageFileContent`. I suggest you edit your title to reflect the real issue

Comment: Have you already set up the file share `$azureFileShare`?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have updated the title. And yes, the file share is already set up.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question from this link [How can I copy the contents of a .csv file placed in a azure file storage, to a powershell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54277036/how-can-i-copy-the-contents-of-a-csv-file-placed-in-a-azure-file-storage-to-a)

I used Get-AzureStorageFileContent to download the file to the $evn:temp folder in powershell runbook, then used it in the Invoke-Sqlcmd.

```
Get-AzureStorageFileContent -ShareName $azureFileShare -Path $azureFilePath -Destination $env:temp -Context $context

# Set Connection parameters
$params = @{
    'Database' = $Database
    'ServerInstance' = $ServerInstance
    'Username' = $dbusername
    'Password' = $dbpassword
    'InputFile' = $env:temp

}

Invoke-Sqlcmd @params
```