# Pass Azure Container File content as parameter to Azure Automation Runbook

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-automation, azure-runbook

i have a csv file in Blob Container which contains list of users. I have a powershell script which add particular use to AD in Azure runbook. How can i read the all users in csv and parse the powershell script for each user.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good solution on how to work with the CSV file - you have to download it directly to your temporary runbook folder:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54282747/1595293

Then you will have to use Import-Csv module for Powershell https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7

Code for loop over users rows should be similar to the snippet:

```
Import-Csv $path | Foreach-Object { 

    foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties)
    {
        doSomething $property.Name, $property.Value
    } 
}
```